# Simplify Equation with Random Variables

Tags: probability, linear-model, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'm wondering if whether the following problem has a solution.
Suppose we have i random variables, all independent, and all following a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p_i$ (all $p_i$'s are different).
If $V_1 = X \cdot Y$, then $P(V_1 = 1) = P(X = 1) \cdot P(Y = 1)$.
If $V_2 = X + Y$, i can use the Poisson Binomial distribution to perform the computations.
If $V_3 = X \cdot Y + X \cdot Z$, i can rewrite as $X \cdot (Y + Z)$ and use again the Poisson Binomial to compute $Y+Z$ and multiply the result with $P(X = 1)$.
I'm interested in only sum and product of random variables (I don't care the other arithmetic operations).

My question is: suppose that i have $V_4 = A \cdot B + B \cdot C + C \cdot D$. Clearly, i cannot group the variables as before and apply the same trick. For example, $B \cdot (A + C) + C \cdot D$ but i cannot apply the Poisson Binomial distribution to $A + C$ since $C$ is involved in another computation (and I will overestimate the probability). In general, how can I rearrange these equations to use the Poisson Binomial to compute the probability (eventually multiplied by the probability of a variable that is not involved in the Poisson Binomial)? I suppose that i need to subtract some values, to get the correct probability, but is not clear to me what values. Any idea or pointer to some references?

Hope the question is somehow clear.

Comment: Saying "Poisson Binomial" seems to be shorthand for "consider all the possibilities", which you can also do for $V_4$.

Comment: Yes, but there are ways to compute the Possion Binomial without enumerating all the possibilities, which are not always applicable in the general case ($V_4$ for example) @Henry

Comment: Indeed, and $V_4$ is only non-zero if at least one of $B$ and $C$ is non-zero (or $A$ and $C$, or $B$ and $D$).  But something similar can be said for $V_3$

Comment: But $V_4 = A \cdot B + B \cdot C + C \cdot D $ is not equivalent to $A \cdot C + B \cdot D$. Or did I miss something?

Comment: What exactly is the expression you want to simplify?  Only $V_4,$ or some generalization?  Since the problem for $V_4$ is almost trivial, I have presumed you want to generalize, but how?

Comment: @whuber i would like to modifiy a general expression involving only sum and products of Bernoulli random variables in such i way i can use only Poisson Binomial distributions (eventually multiplied by another variable, as in $V_3$, or subtracting values). For $V_4$, is not clear to me how to do it (see the example). In the end, i would like to compute the pmf of the variable resulting from this equation (for example, $V_4$).

Comment: In general you can't do it.  Moreover, the most general expression has $2^n$ terms with $n$ random variables and obviously there's no simplification there.  There is a basic problem with your question, though: why insist on expressing the result in terms of Poisson-Binomial distributions?  That seems an unnecessary restraint that only complicates the underlying problem.